# LinearLayout add elements right of a view that fills parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following situation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.myappnamespace.old.widgets.RoundBorderedImageView
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            app:src="@drawable/avatar_john_doe"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:borderColor="#ff0"
            />

        <com.myappnamespace.old.widgets.ConversationCloud
            android:id="@+id/block"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some dummy text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue."
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/message2"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some dummy text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue."
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.myappnamespace.old.widgets.ConversationCloud
            android:id="@+id/block2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:cloud_direction="right"
            />

        <com.myappnamespace.old.widgets.RoundBorderedImageView
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            app:src="@drawable/avatar_john_doe"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:borderColor="#ff0"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of the layout]

The message block of the first row is filling up the space, because it has two view elements ahead of it and `layout_height="fill_parent"`. This is working fine, but I'm struggling to get the same result for the second row, with the exception that the message block is on the left. If I do that with `fill_parent` on the message, it fills up the whole screen. I am looking for a way (without modifying the layout with Java code) to let the avatar and the `ConversationCould` image push the message block to the left.

In the code I have set the width of the second message block to 100dp to demonstrate how it should look like (but then empty space filled up).

I have tried a relative layout instead of a linear layout, but that doesn't work, because of the needed gravity bottom.

I hope someone is more experienced in this and can offer a solution. Your help is appreciated.

*Edit: the textview is inside a relative layout, because I need to add extra views there later..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `weight=1` and `width=0dp` for relativelayout the text inside should have `match_parent` for width

Comment: Confirmed this is working. I was playing around with weights with weights on all elements, but that didn't sort out. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

try this. u should give weight 3 to ur conversationcloud and 1 to image

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.myappnamespace.old.widgets.RoundBorderedImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            app:src="@drawable/avatar_john_doe"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:borderColor="#ff0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <com.myappnamespace.old.widgets.ConversationCloud
            android:id="@+id/block"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="3">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some dummy text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue."
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```